# Jenkins Running but not accessible through public IP address

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in my local machine (ubuntu 19.10).
I can connect to the Jenkins by using `localhost:8080` or `192.168.100.20:8080`.
However, I cannot connect to the Jenkins by using my public ip address !!

I tried to resolve this issue by

1. Modifying `/etc/default/jenkins`. I modified HTTP_HOST to `$HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0` and the `$HTTP_PORT=8080`
2. The JENKINS_ARGS in Jenkins file is

> JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT
> --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST"

3. Restart the Jenkins service: `sudo service jenkins restart` and `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart`
4. Verify the `jenkins.log` file from `/var/log/jenkins`. It looks work without error
5. I have disabled ufw `sudo ufw disable`

And, when I try in my browser `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080` it does not work !
Why Please ?

Comment: As is the case with 99% of computers connected to the internet, your computer most probably is not available at all from its public ip. This is not related to Jenkins.

Comment: @MaratC What do you mean "your computer most probably is not available at all from its public ip" ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to open port 8080 on the firewall for inbound traffic.